# WordPress redirect issue with php

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

i have some users in my db. The PHP script pick the users accurately, but redirect not working.

Please help any one my script is below:

```
if($sqlquery==1)
{
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['password']=$password;
    wp_redirect( 'https://mcqpage.com/somepage', 301 );
    exit; 
} 
else
{
    header("location:http://www.mcqpage.com/index.php"); 
}
```

my detail are as follow

> login page

```
<form onsubmit='return formValidator()' action='https://mcqpage.com/connection/' method='post'>
        <h2>Enter Your Details</h2><hr/>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input type='text' name ='addr1' id='addr' /><br />
        
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        
    
        
        <input type='submit' value='Check Form'  />
```

> connection page

```
> [insert_php]

session_start();

if($_POST['addr1']!="" && $_POST['password']!=""){

session_start();

$connec=@mysql_connect("") or
 mysql_error();

        if (!$connec) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

    $email=$_POST['addr1'];

//echo"$email";

$password= $_POST['password']);  

if ($email=="")
 {
    echo "Enter User Name.......";
 }

else


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE 

password='$password' and name='$email'");

    $data = mysql_num_rows($result);

 

    if($data==1)
      {
         $_SESSION['email']=$email;

          $_SESSION['password']=$password;

wp_redirect( 'https://mcqpage.com/page', 301 );

 exit; 

      } 
    else
    {
        header("location:http://www.mcqpage.com/index.php"); 
    }  
 }
 
//connection closed
mysql_close ($connec);}
else{
        header("location:http://www.mcqpage.com/index.php"); 
}
[/insert_php]
```

@Nadav My error_log shows the following error:

```
> [02-May-2017 07:29:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:237) in /home/mysite/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(47) : eval()'d code on line 2
> 
> [02-May-2017 07:29:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/mysite/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:237) in /home/mysitec/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(47) : eval()'d code on line 2
> 
> [02-May-2017 07:29:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysitec/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:237) in /home/mysite/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(47) : eval()'d code on line 25
```

Comment: which one is work header() or wp_redirect()

Comment: which hook you are using?

Comment: Are you getting any error ? show us if so ..  is it going inside `if` condition or `else` condition .. please be more clear towards it.

Comment: I haven't used wp_redirect, but usually when I have issue with header it's because headers have already been sent (there are a bunch of answers here for that). If it's header, try ensuring there is no whitespace before php tag. Failing that call ob_start() at beginning and ob_flush() at the end

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave it  not showing any error, my code is below

Answer (score 0):

please check it if useful for u

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-how-to-create-a-redirect-from-a-home-page-to-any-url-using-the-php-redirect.html#gref

```
$location = get_site_url() . "/contact";
wp_redirect( $location, 301 );
exit;
```

Comment: my code contain some values which i want to send to another page through session

Comment: session variables access any page check it  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72744

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing your redirect after the headers have already been sent? 
If so it will not work. Please make sure that your code is running before the headers are sent, preferably as part of the [template_redirect hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) that Wordpress offers.

If you are not sure where your code is being loaded I suggest you incpsulate your code inside a function that runs during the template_redirect hook. For example, you can add the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function handle_session_data()
{
  //Your code here.
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'handle_session_data' );
```

Comment: i am newbie and  i have showed you  my two pages above pls check it

Comment: what do you mean by "your code"?, i think you are saying that i put the redirect code here

Comment: All the PHP code that is related to the redirection process. Any check and redirection that needs to be done before page load should be put there.

Answer (score 0):

the following code solved my problem

`function register_my_session()

{

if( !session_id() )

{

```
session_start();
```

}

}`
in function.php

and start the session without any error, for header, i used the java script redirect, this solved my problem